# How can I use ANY public class referenced online

Tags: android, class, xamarin, reference

In Xamarin, how can I get the correct information to implement any class in an application.

I will use this class reference as an example: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html

The class type is `SupportMapFragment`. How can I create an activity that extends `SupportMapFragment`?

The only information that I can see on this page is the following:

> java.lang.Object
>      ↳  android.support.v4.app.Fragment
>        ↳    com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

How use the SupportMapFragment class in a new activity?

Can I please have a step by step list of instructions on how to do this? Not just for this `SupportMapFragment` class, but any class that I find on a web resource such as the link at the top of this post.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the project created you need to add the Google Play component to it. Right click on Components (below References) and select "Get More Components...". The version you want depends on you but for examples sake select "Google Play Services (Gingerbread)" and add it to your app.

Next you need to increase the Java heap size so on project settings go to "Android Build" -> "Advanced" and set "Java heap size" to 1GB. Now the project should build successfully again.

Create the class:

```
public class SupportMap : Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment
{
```

Use it in layout:

```
<fragment 
    class="yourclassnamespacehereinlowercase.SupportMap"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

[More information on fragments can be found from Xamarin documentation.](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/)